# Bug in Magento transaction email

Tags: magento, transactions, confirmation-email

I am using Magento for less than a week and my problem is that transaction email which is sent to the customer does not show the billing address and also the payment method is like below image :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pTr1.jpg)

Please let me know how can I solve this problem.
Thank you in advance.
Mojtaba

Comment: you need to load transaction email from admin, and check is there any error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?